# how to write more than one insert statements in stored procedure with two table parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have two tables

```
Employee---->Id(identity),FN,LN,Address

EmpContact--->Id(identity),Empid(Above table identity value),ContactType,ContactNumber
```

How to write two tables and insert statements in the single stored procedure. The second table "EmpContact" needs the resulting Identity ID from insertion in the first table "Employee"

Comment: This is fine to do. Have you tried it? - what problem are you having? Also, what database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is SCOPE_IDENTITY() function, it returns last ID within a scope

```
insert into Employee(FN,LN, Adress)
values(@var1, @var2, @var3)

declare @EmpID int 
set @EmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into EmpContact(Empid, ContactType, contactNumber)
values(@EmpID, @var4, @var5)
```

Answer (score 0):

ummm... the answer is really simple, just write a procedure with error handling etc.

```
create procedure dbo.myProc
@param

insert into dbo.Employee(FN,LN,Address)
select @value1, @value2, @value3

insert into dbo.EmpContact(Empid,ContactType,ContactNumber)
select ID,@value4, @value5
from dbo.Employee

go
```

Comment: it would insert entire Employee table into EmpContact whenever someone call this procedure

Comment: yes it would, and the question doesn't specify anything other than "a procedure to insert into 2 tables" - which is what this does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your unknown fields are coming in as parameters:

Inside your stored proc...

```
DECLARE @EmployeeID BIGINT --Or whatever datatype you are using

INSERT INTO Employee
    (FN, LN, Address)
VALUES
    (@FN, @LN, @Address)

SET @EmployeeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  --This is probably the line you are looking for

INSERT INTO EmpContact
    (Empid, ContractType, ContractNumber)
VALUES
    (@EmployeeID, @ContractType, @ContractNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc yourproc
(
   -- parameter definitions here
)
as
begin
        insert into Employee
        (FN,LN,Address) 
        values 
        (@FN,@LN,@Address)

declare @EmployeeID int 
set @EmployeeID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

        insert into EmpContact
        (Empid, ContactType, ContactNumber) 
        values 
        (@EmployeeID, @ContactType, @ContactNumber) 
end
```

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are
>   generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is
>   not limited to a specific scope.

[SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the original insert things, but the Identity ID from insertion in the first table you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, it  returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.